# Column not wrapping around floated elements

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
 background-color: lightgreen;
}

.column {
 width: 31.33%;
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 1%;
}

.column:last-child {
 float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='column'>Column 1</div>
    <div class='column'>Column 2</div>
    <div class='column'>Column 3Column 3Column 3Column 3Column 3Column 3Column 3</div>
</div>
```

Why does column three not wrap around like this: [image]

There is enough space for it on the right of the floated elements.

Answer (score 3):

Add width: 100% to the .column:last-child.

```
.column:last-child {
    float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage of the content of the last column floating below column1/2, if you don't want that behavoiur check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35960999/4068027)

Comment: @Aides But that is exactly what the OP wants, even an image is added to show that

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why the above happens?

Comment: Because it has width of 31.33% and cannot wrap around. That's why we made it 100%.

Answer (score 0):

The answer why this happens is pretty much the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35965336/4651083) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965264/float-with-content-that-floats-around-and-one-that-is-underneath)

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/ykem4znc/) demonstrating that the 3rd column is below the floated columns, and it's text content is simply wrapping around (below in this case) the floated column.

(simply made some backgrounds translucent)

```
.column {
    width: 31.33%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255,0, .5);
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1%;
}

.column:last-child {
    float: none;
  background: red;
}
```