# Right floated element below regular paragraph with width

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
 <div id='container'>
  <p>This is some text contained within a small-ish box. I'm using it as an example of how placing your floated elements in different orders in your HTML can affect your layouts. For example, take a look at this great photo placeholder that should be sitting on the right.</p>
 <img src='image.gif'>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

p {
    width: 100px;
}

img {
    float: right;
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/y9Lqjm1f/

Why if the paragraph's width is small enough does the floated right element not appear at the top of the container div?

Comment: I'm not sure the answer to your question exactly, but I was just playing with your fiddle and noticed that if you add `display: inline-block` to the paragraph styling and make the paragraph's width small enough, the image will appear at the top of the container div.

Comment: Float first - http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101#section5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `img` element is placed below the `p` element which follows the normal flow as a `block element`.

`img`'s separate flow, which results from it having a `float` style applied, only begins below the `p`.

If you added another `p` below the `img` it would follow normal layout flow as if the `img` did not exist, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/y9Lqjm1f/1/

In short, in order for the `img` to appear to the top, it has to be placed first in the markup, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/y9Lqjm1f/2/

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35965336/4651083) about `float` and `block element`s

In general:

- Floated elements respect previous block elements' layout flow, meaning they appear below the previous block element
- Block elements following the floated element disregard the floated element, and keep their normal layout flow as if the floated element did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

`p` and `img` tags are block level elements. They create new line for next element. So, `float: right;` property in `img` apply in new line.

You can use `display: inline-block;` for both `p` and `img` tags.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/mrinal013/pen/XdjNXz)